# Save a pickle file without using open(filename, 'wb')

Tags: python, azure-pipelines, pickle, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to create an azure machine learning pipeline with tensorflow estimator step, and the output is a pickle file, but I'm not able to save the file. Any clues on how to fix this?

```
Starting the daemon thread to refresh tokens in background for process with pid = 138
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 64, in <module>
    joblib.dump(data, output_path)
  File "/azureml-envs/azureml_cb121c6a55dfafffd79cca4bedd52636/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in dump
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/azureml/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/output_data/data.pkl'
```

Comment: You have a directory with that name already; presumably you can just delete it, thus allowing your pickle file to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to save a file `data.pkl` to a directory `/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/azureml/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/output_data` that already has a directory (not file) named `data.pkl`. Try removing the directory `data.pkl` first before re-running. If the error appears again, you must be accidentally creating the directory `data.pkl` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks! Had to delete the file that was created in a previous run!